# Move computer to the correct OU from csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, ou

Keep getting `"Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty."` when trying to move computers to their respective OU.

Tried these set of codes to achieve it but it doesn't work:

```
PS C:\temp> cat .\OUs.csv
OUName,Server
AD-DNS,AD-DNS-Server
Apps,App-Server
DBs,DB-Server1
DBs,DB-Server2
Utilities-Servers,Utils-Server
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> $CSVFile = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
PS C:\temp> foreach ($item in $CSVFile){
>> $computer = (Get-ADComputer $item.Server).DistinguishedName
>> $targetOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter "name -eq '$item.OUName'")
>>     Move-ADObject -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
>>     Write-Host "Computer $computer has been moved successfully to $targetOU"
>> }
```

But if I change

```
$targetOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter "name -eq '$item.OUName'")
```

to a specific OU, like this:

```
$targetOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter "name -eq 'AD-DNS'")
```

all the computers go to AD-DNS OU.
Here's a session capture when I executed the code:

```
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> cat .\OUs.csv
OUName,Server
AD-DNS,AD-DNS-Server
Apps,App-Server
DBs,DB-Server1
DBs,DB-Server2
Utilities-Servers,Utils-Server
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> $CSVFile = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
PS C:\temp> foreach ($item in $CSVFile){
>> $computer = (Get-ADComputer $item.Server).DistinguishedName
>> $targetOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter "name -eq '$item.OUName'")
>>     Move-ADObject -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
>>     Write-Host "Computer $computer has been moved successfully to $targetOU"
>> }
Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:51
+ ... t -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confir ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject

Computer CN=AD-DNS-Server,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to
Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:51
+ ... t -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confir ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject

Computer CN=App-Server,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to
Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:51
+ ... t -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confir ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject

Computer CN=DB-Server1,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to
Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:51
+ ... t -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confir ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject

Computer CN=DB-Server2,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to
Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'TargetPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:51
+ ... t -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confir ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject

Computer CN=Utils-Server,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to
PS C:\temp>
```

Expectation is that `Server` should get moved to it's corresponding `OU`.

Appreciate your help! Thank you.

Update1:
I tried changing the code to the following:

```
$CSVFile = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
foreach ($item in $CSVFile){
$computer = (Get-ADComputer $item.Server).DistinguishedName
$targetOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter "name -eq '$item.OUName'").DistinguishedName
    Move-ADObject -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host "Computer $computer has been moved successfully to $targetOU"
}
```

still got the same error.

Update 2:
This works:

```
$CSVFile = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
foreach ($item in $CSVFile){
    $computer = (Get-ADComputer $item.Server).DistinguishedName
    $targetOU = Get-ADObject -Filter "Name -eq '$($item.OUName)'"
    Move-ADObject -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host "Computer $computer has been moved successfully to $targetOU"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a property in a variable inside a quoted string, you have to escape it with `$(...)` to have it evaluated as an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6). So your code becomes:

```
$targetOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter "name -eq '$($item.OUName)'")
```